# when i add a navbar, there is added whitespace below my content. how do i remove this?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-modal, navbar

just creating a practice landing page. everything looks great until i add the navbar. once i add the navbar it creates a scrollbar on the side and when you scroll down there is this white space at the bottom of the page. i want to remove the white space and scrollbar. here is my code, thanks

(background image) https://i.stack.imgur.com/jYNuY.jpg

```css
body {
 color: white;
 background-image: url("background.jpg");
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size: cover;
 background-position: center;
 height: 100vh;
}

.container {
 height: 100vh;
 display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
}

#title {
 font-family: 'Lora', serif;
 font-size: 3em;
 text-shadow: 2px black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>bootstrap</title>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

 <nav class="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark">
   <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Landing page</a>
   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
     <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
     <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
       <li class="nav-item active">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item dropdown">
         <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
           Dropdown
         </a>
         <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
           <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
           <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
         </div>
       </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
         <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
       </li>
     </ul>
     <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
       <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
       <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
     </form>
   </div>
 </nav>


 <div class="container">
  <h1 id="title">The wait is over.</h1>
   <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">Find out more!</button>
 </div>

 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is add the class `.fixed-top` to the navbar

```
<nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-dark bg-dark">
```

Let me know if that helps you! [Here](https://codepen.io/federicomartin/pen/dQpgxb) you have a codepen if you want to test it.